# Pygame, choppy movement

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

So I've noticed that character only moves when my velocity is greater than 1 and is an integer but the question is why I can't use move_ip() function to have my character move slower than 1 velocity and in between 1 and 0?.

Here is the code that I use:

```
def Physics():
    for k, v in enumerate(ENTITIES):
        vel     = ENTITIES[k].GetVelocity()
        pos     = ENTITIES[k].GetPos()

        vel[1] = vel[1] + 0.1
        ENTITIES[k].Entity.move_ip(vel)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Rect` class is typically used to describe an area of the screen, and pixels are integer values, and thus the properties of the `Rect` class are integers also (you can't draw something at position `(1.3, 5.7)`, since that position does not exit on the screen).

If you want to keep track of a sub-pixel position, such as `4.5` or `1.2`, you have to store it in another variable/field of your class.

Comment: I don't store sub-pixel positions in rect class. I have a class where self.Entity = rect object and my position is stored in self.Position

Comment: If you're updating the position in another variable, round x and y and set the `rect.center` attribute instead of using `move_ip`